# I want to display webpage on a mobile with full content

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, viewport, meta

I have webpage which is already displaying on a mobile with proper look and feel as on desktop. I'm having trouble displaying the site content with minimum zoom on so that all the content of the site will display properly without any scrolling.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. What your looking for is **media queries** or you want to build a **Responsive Website**. This will allow your website to look different depending on the screen resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this meta in your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) if you are looking for responsive webpage design. This will solve your scrolling problem